# Xamarin: MissingManifestResourceException when trying to access a resource

Tags: c#, xamarin, localization, visual-studio-2017, xamarin.uwp

## Introduction

I am creating my first Xamarin app (that will target UWP first, then Android, finally maybe iOS).

Basically, the app needs multiple languages: English (Default), French, Spanish, Russian and Swedish at least.

I am trying to add less Platform specific code, so no specific code has been added, for localization.

I used the [UseResxLocaliaztion Xamarin GitHub project](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UsingResxLocalization) with the [Xamarin Localization Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/).

Basically, I just copy and try to use this project resources on mine. But namespace was `UsingResxLocalization.Resx` and mine is `WhoStart.Resources`, same for the folder name which is `Resources` instead of `Resx`.

I updated the `ResourceManager` property of the `Designer.cs` file, and try different things with the resx properties, like change the `Generator` and the `CustomToolNamespace` with no results.

I manually changed the `WhoStart.projitems` file in some points since my VisualStudio didn't indent files and can't generate the `Designer.cs` file.

## My environment

- Windows 10 v1607 Anniversary Update (14393.1066)
- Visual Studio 2017 v15.1 (26403.7)
- Xamarin 4.4.0.34
- NuGet packages :

  - Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.231
  - Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.3.3

## The problem

I am having a System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException when trying to access a resource propety.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
Debug.WriteLine(AppResources.AddButton);
```

> **System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException** : 'Could not find
>   any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral
>   culture. Make sure "WhoStart.Resources.AppResources.resources" was
>   correctly embedded or linked into assembly "WhoStart.UWP" at compile
>   time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and
>   fully signed.'

**Visual Studio**

I thougth maybe it cames from my environment :

- When I create a resource file with Visual Studio wizard, it creates a .resw file.
- Visual Studio don't autogenerate the `Designer.cs` file
- When I open the .resx file, the **Access Modifier** menu is disabled.
- It seems that I don't have all project properties I noticed on forums
- I don't have a "Run Custom Tool" when right clicking a .resx file

## The code

**AppResources.resx**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <resheader name="resmimetype">
        <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="version">
        <value>2.0</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>

    <data name="AddButton" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Add new item</value>
        <comment>this string appears on a button to add a new item to the list</comment>
    </data>
</root>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace WhoStart.Resources {
    using System.Reflection;


    /// <summary>
    ///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
    /// </summary>
    // This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
    // class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
    // To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
    // with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    internal class AppResources {

        private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

        private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;

        [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
        internal AppResources() {
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("WhoStart.Resources.AppResources", typeof(AppResources).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
        ///   resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
            get {
                return resourceCulture;
            }
            set {
                resourceCulture = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Looks up a localized string similar to Add new item.
        /// </summary>
        internal static string AddButton {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("AddButton", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**WhoStart.projitems**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildAllProjects>$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)</MSBuildAllProjects>
    <HasSharedItems>true</HasSharedItems>
    <SharedGUID>2f09a751-1235-4d87-8839-d5828319ad81</SharedGUID>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration">
    <Import_RootNamespace>WhoStart</Import_RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)ColorUtil.cs" />
    <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)ILocalize.cs" />
    <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)MainPage.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Resources\AppResources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>AppResources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Resources\AppResources.es.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>AppResources.es.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Resources\AppResources.fr.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>AppResources.fr.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)TranslateExtension.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)MainPage.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)App.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Resources\AppResources.es.resx">
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>AppResources.es.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <CustomToolNamespace>WhoStart.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Resources\AppResources.fr.resx">
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>AppResources.fr.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <CustomToolNamespace>WhoStart.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Resources\AppResources.resx">
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>AppResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <CustomToolNamespace>WhoStart.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

## Research

- [C# - Create designer.cs file from ResXRersourcewriter generated resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153933/create-designer-cs-file-from-resxrersourcewriter-generated-resource-file)
- [Public Strongly Typed Resources With PublicResXFileCodeGenerator](http://guysmithferrier.com/post/2008/06/Public-Strongly-Typed-Resources-With-PublicResXFileCodeGenerator.aspx)
- [C# - Generating Resx files for MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997901/generating-resx-files-for-mvc)
- [C# - Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690713/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutra)
- [Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/30d3f13f-0f2e-4852-833f-32d3f557c38a/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutral-culture?forum=winforms)
- [C# - Localization and Resource Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719930/c-sharp-localization-and-resource-files)
- [C# - Using ResourceManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825433/using-resourcemanager)
- [Internationalization of a Cross Platform Application](http://blog.giovannimodica.com/post/internationalization-of-a-cross-platform-application)

Comment: Have you set the `Build Action` of  resx file property as `Embedded Resource`?

Comment: As you can see in the `WhoStart.projitems` file, yes I did :) I post this file too to check if the properties are right, maybe they are. I just don't hope a Visual Studio 2017 bug ...